# How to pass an array of values of same query parameter to the router?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

As seen in [this bug fix](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11373) it is possible to define multiple query parameters of the same name in a url and have them serialized to an array:

```
http://localhost:4200?status=Deleted&status=Audio Issue
```

becomes:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      if (!params) {
        return;
      }
      console.log(params); // see below
    // {
    //   'status': [
    //     'Deleted',
    //     'Audio Issue'
    //   ],
    // }
```

However from my testing the reverse isn't true:

```
let queryParams = {
  'status': [
    'Deleted', 
    'Audio Issue',      
  ],
}

this.router.navigate([], { queryParams });
```

becomes:

```
http://localhost:4200?status=Deleted,Audio Issue
```

When I'd like it to produce:

```
http://localhost:4200?status=Deleted&status=Audio Issue
```

Is there any way to do this?

If your answer is to parse the comma delimited value, why have the router produce this functionality in one direction and not the other?

**Edit:**

Possibly fixed 6 days ago https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15129

Comment: I answered on the PR.

Comment: @n00dl3 You or jcroll should probably answer this question so it doesn't stay open forever. It's good to know this works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this functionality is fixed in Angular 4 see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15129